# Let $A\subseteq R$ be non-empty and bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

> Let $A\subseteq R$ be non-empty and bounded .
>   Prove that
>   $\sup A - \inf A =$ $\inf\lbrace b - a : a, b \in R$ and $ a\leq A \leq b \rbrace$

---

My attempt : Let $A$ be  any nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R} $ then suppose inf A = a and sup A = b. It means
$\sup A - \inf A = b-a $ and the given

$= \inf \lbrace b-a, b+\epsilon -a, b+\epsilon - a+\epsilon_1 \rbrace$

$= b-a.$

Hence proved.

Is it correct?

Comment: "Prove that $\sup A - \inf A =$ $\lbrace b - a : a, b \in R$ and $ a\leq A \leq b \rbrace$" - is there a typo or an omission here? The LHS is a number, and the RHS is a set.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure how what you've written is a proof. It seems like you just assumed  what $\inf A$ and $\sup A$ were. I think the problem is to show that $\inf A = a$ and $\sup B = b$, then it is clear that $\sup A - \inf A = b-a$. To show that $a$ is the infimum of $A$, just assume that there is a greater lower bound and argue by contradiction. (It is clear that $a$ is a lower bound). Then do the essentially the same thing with $b$ by assuming there is a smaller upper bound and arguing by contradiction.